# How do we set up breeze.js in angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, webpack, breeze

The instructions for getting breeze to work with angular 2 assume there is a systemjs.config.js.

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.bridge.angular

However, the angular CLI now uses webpack rather than SystemJS. Do we have to do something different for the new version or do we just skip the steps for systemjs.config.js?

Comment: as long as you npm installed the breeze client you do not have to do any thing else. just skip the systemjs.config.js

Comment: You can switch to the newer [breeze.bridge2.angular](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.bridge2.angular) if you wish to use HttpClient